# Run command after each type/insert in particular buffer

Tags: hooks, advice, insert

I'm implementing a (optional, de-activable) real-time syntax checker. Each time the user types/deletes anything, I want to run my spell-checking funtion :

I tried `(add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook 'syntax-check-continuous)` but now even when I type in the minibuffer, the function is run.

What would be the good practice for that? An `advice` after an insert function? An `(add-to-list 'before-change-functions 'syntax-check-continuous)`?

I'd really like to see existing real-time syntax checker implementations, I don't want to make Emacs behave in a weird way.

Comment: Take a look at `flymake-mode`. It can run a compiler or a linter on a buffer from time to time. There's also `flyspell-mode` (with a variant for `prog-mode` descendants as well) that runs a spell checker on what you type into a buffer. Both of them ship with Emacs.

Comment: But how will those packages know about my language? Apparently (https://www.google.com/search?q=flyspell-mode+flymake-mode+faust) they don't. Furthermore, it's not just a syntax check, a build is launched in the background ; lots of things happen. I just want to know how to `(message "type!")` after each key press *in the my-mode buffers*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `add-hook` is global, but you can pass an optional argument to add the hook only for the current buffer. From the `add-hook` doc string:

> (add-hook HOOK FUNCTION &optional APPEND LOCAL)
>
> The optional fourth argument, LOCAL, if non-nil, says to modify the hook’s
>   buffer-local value rather than its global value.

It sounds like you want your mode to add a buffer-local hook when it is enabled. Try:

```
(add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook 'syntax-check-continuous nil t)
```