# Buffer-local after-save-hook?

Tags: hooks, buffer-local

I'd like to register an `after-save-hook` that is only active in certain buffers that I specify.

For example, assume there are 3 functions currently registered in my `after-save-hook`: `hook-01`, `hook-02`, and `hook-03`. In all cases after `save-buffer` is called, I'd like `hook-01`, `hook-02`, and `hook-03` to be invoked, and I realize that this is the normal `after-save-hook` behavior.

However, in certain buffers and ***only*** those buffers, I want an additional hook, `special-hook`, to also be called after `save-buffer` is invoked, so that in these special buffers, all 4 hooks are run after the buffer is saved.

Is there a way to register a hook function that is added to `after-save-hook` only within certain specified buffers?

I control when those special buffers are entered, so I can cause special elisp code to run upon entry into those buffers. I just don't know how to specify a hook that is only valid in a given buffer.

Comment: Probably a better way is to just check in special-hook if you are in one of your special buffers.  That way, other code can still add hooks to after-save-hook.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run command after each type/insert](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34304/run-command-after-each-type-insert)

Answer (score 10):

This is standard functionality built into `add-hook`:

> add-hook is a compiled Lisp function in ‘subr.el’.
>
> (add-hook HOOK FUNCTION &optional APPEND **LOCAL**)
>
> Add to the value of HOOK the function FUNCTION.
>   FUNCTION is not added if already present.
>   FUNCTION is added (if necessary) at the beginning of the hook list
>   unless the optional argument APPEND is non-nil, in which case
>   FUNCTION is added at the end.
>
> **The optional fourth argument, LOCAL, if non-nil, says to modify
>   the hook’s buffer-local value rather than its global value.
>   This makes the hook buffer-local, and it makes t a member of the
>   buffer-local value.  That acts as a flag to run the hook
>   functions of the global value as well as in the local value.**
>
> HOOK should be a symbol, and FUNCTION may be any valid function.  If
>   HOOK is void, it is first set to nil.  If HOOK’s value is a single
>   function, it is changed to a list of functions.

Comment: in emacs 27.2 `append` is now an index called `depth` in the (conventional) range of -100 to 100, defaulting to 0. if you pass `t` that counts as 90.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, this is easier than I thought. Upon entering the special buffer, all I have to do is this ...

```
(make-variable-buffer-local 'after-save-hook)
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'special-hook)
```

I had tried that before and thought it didn't work, but now I realize that I was testing it incorrectly.

Comment: You can also use `(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'special-hook nil t)`, the last argument means to add to the buffer local value.

Comment: @HippoMan `make-variable-buffer-local` makes the specified var buffer-local "whenever it is set". It is used in tandem with a variable *definition* (although nowadays you typically would use `defvar-local`). To make an existing var have a buffer-local value in the *current* buffer, you would in general use `make-local-variable` (or nowadays `setq-local`) -- but for hooks you don't want that either, because as npostavs points out `add-hook` has direct support for what you want to do.